# Let $U_1$ and $U_2$ be independent and uniform on $[0, 1]$, find and sketch the density function of $S = U_1 + U_2$

Tags: statistics

I am stuck on this problem during my review for my stats test.

I know I have to use the convolution formula, and I understand that:

$f_{U_1}(U_1) = 1$ for $0≤U_1≤1$

$f_{U_2}(U_2) = 1$ for $0≤U_2≤1$

but I do not know how to continue on from there.  How do I use the convolution formula in this question?  Thanks

Comment: what difficulty did you face when you tried the formula?

Comment: I'm not sure how to even set up the equation.  I'm guessing I start off with $\int dU_1dU_2$.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are OK with the convolution formula then it is just a bit of computation. Letting $f_{U_1}(x) = f_{U_2}(x) = 1$ for $x \in [0,1]$ and $0$ elsewhere, and $S = U_1 + U_2$. The convolution of $f_{U_1}$ and  $f_{U_2}$ gives us the probability density function of $f_S$, it is
$$ f_S(z) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{U_1}(z-x)f_{U_2}(x) \, \mathrm{d}x. $$
Since $f_{U_2}(x) = 1$ on $[0,1]$  we have
$$f_S(z) = \int_0^1 f_{U_1}(z-x) \, \mathrm{d}x.$$
We now have to consider cases since $f_{U_1}(z-x) = 1$ only when $ 0\leq z-x \leq 1$, or equivalently when $z-1\leq x\leq z$. Thus, for $0\leq z\leq 1$ we have 
$$f_S(z) = \int_0^z \, \mathrm{d}x = z.$$
And, for $1\leq z\leq 2$, we have
$$f_S(z) = \int_{z-1}^1 \, \mathrm{d}x = 2-z.$$

Comment: thanks, but I don't understand why we need to consider $1≤z≤2$.  I have also seen in the textbook answer that we need to have 2 regions, but is it because we have to consider the region of S which goes from 0 to 2 as $S = U_1 + U_2$?

Comment: We need to consider $1\leq z\leq 2$ since it may be the case that $0\leq z-x \leq 1$ and so $f_{U_1}(z-x) = 1.$ As mentioned above, $f_{U_1}(z-x) = 1$ is satisfied whenever $z-1\leq x\leq z$ and note that we are only considering $0\leq x\leq 1$ from the limits of the integral. We need to consider the two regions since both inequalities can be satisfied for each region: for $0\leq z\leq 1$ - the inequalities are satisfied whenever $0\leq x\leq z$; for $1\leq z \leq 2$ - the inequalities are satisfied whenever $z-1\leq x\leq 1$. Hopefully this helps?

Answer (score 0):

Let $s \in [0,2]$

\begin{align}
f_S(s) &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{U_1}(t)f_{U_2}(s-t) \, dt \\
&= \int_0^1 1\cdot f_{U_2}(s-t) \, dt
\end{align}

Now we just need to integrate over the region when $f_{U_2}$ is positive.

$$0 \le s-t \le 1$$

$$-1 \le t-s \le 0$$

$$s-1 \le t \le s$$

Hence

$$f_S(s) = \int_{\max(0,s-1)}^{\min{(1,s)}} 1 \, dt$$

I will leave the simplication as an exercise.

You might like to consider when $s \ge 1$ and $s<1$.

Remark: In the convoltuion formula, we are integrating only over one variable $t$.

Comment: sorry for asking so much, but I know min(1,s) means the minimum.  But how do you find what it equals to?

Comment: If $s< 1$, then we have $\min(1,s)=s$ and if we have $s \ge 1$, then we have $\min(1,s)=1$.